# If $c > 1$, show that $\sqrt[n]{c}$ approaches $1$ for large $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I know there's a duplicate about this question, but I came up with this solution on my own so I need a verification.

Using Bernoulli's inequality, we obtain $\forall \varepsilon > 0 $, $\exists N > 0$ such that if $n > N$, then $1 < 1 + n\varepsilon \le (1 + \varepsilon)^n$.
However, as $n \to \infty$, $1 + n \varepsilon \to \infty$.
By squeeze theorem, we have $(1 + \varepsilon)^n \to \infty$ as well.

Here comes the part I am not sure of.

**For large enough $n$, we always could have a fixed $c$, such that $(1 + \varepsilon)^n > c$ $\forall \varepsilon > 0$.**

This yields $c^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1 < \varepsilon$. Since $c > 1$, we have $c^{\frac{1}{n}} > 1$, so $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $c^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1 < \varepsilon$ gives the desired result.

Is this proof lacking in any manners? Can we assume the bold sentence?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not what the question asks. You say you can always find a $c$ for any $\epsilon$. But the problem is the other way around: for any $c$ you need to show that there is $\epsilon$ ...

Comment: Actually, the OP needs to show that for any $c>1$ and for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $(1+\varepsilon)^n>c$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: @Andrei Okay. How about this: since $(1 + \varepsilon)^n \to \infty$,  $\forall c > 1$, there always exists a $n$ that's big enough to surpass $c$. However I feel it's the same idea as the bold sentence...

Comment: Concerning the bold sentence. If you want to avoid logarithms (in case you haven't yet established their properties), you could provide a very suboptimal value for $n=n(\varepsilon, c)$ such that $(1+\varepsilon)^n > c$ is satisfied for given $\varepsilon, c$. Can you use $(1 + \varepsilon)^k > (1 + \varepsilon) \varepsilon^{k-1} > 1 + k \varepsilon$ maybe? And then take $k = (c -1)/\varepsilon$ as your $n$?

Comment: Bernoulli inequali ty is the other way around....

Comment: We know $(1+\epsilon)^n \ge 1 + n\epsilon$ so if we want $(1+\epsilon)^n > c$ we just need $1+n\epsilon > c$.  And we can get that by letting $n > \frac{c-1}\epsilon$.

Comment: The part you are unsure if is 1) Utterly false and 2) Utterly unneeded.    Your argument by the squeeze theory is complete. "For large enough n, we always could have a fixed c, such that (1+ε)n>c ∀ε>0" is very easy to show to be false.  For $n$ we can always find a $\epsilon: c^{\frac 1n}-1 > \epsilon > 0$.  But that has nothing to do with *your* problem where you have a fixed $\epsilon$ and need to find a large $n$.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood, your explanation really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bold statement is false, I think. As stated it is difficult to parse. Notice that for any $c,n$ (large or fixed or otherwise) $$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} (1+\epsilon)^n=1<c
$$
so the inequality never holds for all $\epsilon$. What you want is for all fixed $c>1$ and $\epsilon>0$ that $$
(1+\epsilon)^n>c
$$
for all $n$ sufficiently large. From there, you get $1<c^{1/n}<1+\epsilon$ and procede as you have already done. But the statement should go with picking $c$ and $\epsilon$ before $n$ since you are taking a limit in $n$.

Comment: Thanks. I see it's the other way around. I will try to rephrase that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

For fixed $c \in \Bbb{R_{> 1}}$ and any $n \in \Bbb{Z_{> 1}}$, binomial expansion gives that

$$\left[ ~1 + \frac{c-1}{n} ~\right]^n > c \implies $$

$$\left[ ~1 + \frac{c-1}{n} ~\right] > c^{(1/n)}.$$

Also, for fixed $c$,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left[ ~1 + \frac{c-1}{n} ~\right] = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your bold sentence is correct. Here's the proof. For any fixed $c>0$ and for any $\varepsilon>0$ we choose $\displaystyle M=\log_{(1+\varepsilon)}(c)+1$. Then any $n>M$ would do the work and vice-versa.